# Creating a checkout-once type thing with SVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm having to manage some ASPNETDB.MDF files with my subversion repo. Everytime I visit my site it updates something in this file. Which is not what is wanted.

It also can't be readonly or else the site fails to open the file and gives a nice little error.

So what kind of property should I use. This database is only necessary for webpart communication, and really doesn't matter what is inside of it, as the developers never directly change anything in it.

So, I can't just use ignore because I still need the file in the repo.

So what do I do? Just have tell people to copy it in manually?

Comment: Subversion shouldn't be updating the file on the fly. Do you have any properties set on the file at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common solution would be to have the "example" MDF stored in the repository as something like "ASPNETDB.MDF.EXAMPLE" and then the developers copy it to the same directory as "ASPNETDB.MDF".  Then put an ignore on the actual MDF.  I've used this strategy with local configuration files to prevent the constant process of reverting the one file before doing a full commit.